# Oracle APEX 4.2 tabular form data in PLSQL

Tags: oracle-apex

I would like to send the data of rows, where the rows changed in a tabular form (including the read only columns) in email (created a PLSQL process) after submit.

I'm now facing two problems though:

- How can I get the data from the read only columns in PLSQL? They're not mapped into the apex_application.g_f0x array.
- Also, how can I check if a row is modified in PLSQL?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get the data from the read only columns in PLSQL? They're not mapped into the apex_application.g_f0x array.

Use [APEX_ITEM.DISPLAY_AND_SAVE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#AEAPI195)
to get value of Display only Column.

> Also, how can i check if a row is modified in PLSQL?

Use  [APEX$ROW_STATUS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#CHDBDHIF).

Comment: APEX_ITEM.DISPLAY_AND_SAVE worked pretty nicely.

I couldn't use APEX$ROW_STATUS, since it only can be used at row level processes, i guess(?). My process is not associated with the tabular form, because it only has to run once. (gather data -> send email)